# CSS overriding dilemma

Tags: asp.net, css, layout

Basically I have a theme in my ASP.NET application and it contains a css file that turns all my tables blue, which looks great.

It looks like this

```
table
{
    background-color: #DEF1FF;
    border-color: #DEF1FF;
    color:#5793C9;
}
td
{
 // TD properties
}
```

But now I want one table to be a different colour. I created a class to override it:

```
.BlankTable
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#5793C9;
    font-size:medium;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:2px;
}
```

I set a `<table class="BlankTable">` and I have two problems:

firstly, if I put another table inside that one, it does not inherit BlankTable but uses the original table part of the css file

secondly, if I use the td part to set a td specific property (like padding), it doesn't carry across - `<table class="BlankTable><tr><td>hello world</td></tr></table>` results in the  using the td I put in the CSS file.

Ideally what I want is to set my CSS code like this:

```
.Blank
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#5793C9;
    font-size:medium;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:2px;

    table { // properties }
    td { // properties }
}
```

so it uses the table/td properties I specify for the .Blank css class. Is there any way to do this or to refactor my code somehow so I can have all tables looking blue by default, and be able to override it easily?

Comment: If you want to overwrite rules, you can try !important tag. e.g. background-color: #ffffff !important;

Answer (score 3):

You can do that, but the syntax is :

```
.Blank
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#5793C9;
    font-size:medium;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:2px;

}

.Blank table { // properties }
.Blank table td { // properties }
```

These last 2 rules will match a table and td located inside anything with class "Blank".

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
.Blank table {...}
.Blank td {...}
```

Although I must warn you: there are rare cases where you should use a table inside another table.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but it's worth pointing out that this is just one type of CSS selector (the descendant selector). There are all sorts of other [CSS selectors](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200509/css_21_selectors_part_1/) that you might want to use to target specific elements.

It's worth getting familiar with them - you might be surprised with what can (and can't) be done. (Using jQuery will also be a lot easier if you are familiar with CSS selectors.)